# Intuition about conditional sigma algebra

Tags: probability

I have difficulty in interpreting conditional probability given sigma algebra $\mathscr{F}$. 
There is a statement in book<sup>1</sup> about conditional probability. We have sigma algebra $\mathscr{G} \subseteq \mathscr{F}$:

...
*The more sets there are in $\mathscr{G}$ the larger the volume of information, all the way from the trivial set $\mathscr{L}=(\emptyset, \Omega)$(complete ignorance, with $P(B|I)=P(B)$ a.s.) to the set $\mathscr{F}$ itself, which corresponds to **almost sure knowledge of the outcome**.*

In the quote above(and in a lot of other books) I obviously miss some intuition with respect to "given sigma algebra". How we can have "knowledge of the outcome" if $\mathscr{F}$ has controversial information about occurrence of an event? In other words, we don't know that event happened or not if we have given $\mathscr{F}$.

### **Updated notation**

$A \subset \Omega$,

$\mathbf{1_A}(w)$ 
is $\mathscr{F}$-measurable and indicates whether or not $w$ belongs to $A$.

$
\mathbf{1_A}(w) = 
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0 & if\ w \in A \\
  1 & if\ w \notin A\
 \end{array}
\right.
$

$B \subset \mathbb{R}$

$
\mathbf{1^{-1}_A}(B) = 
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \emptyset & if\ \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace  \bigcap B = \{\emptyset\} \\
  A & if\ \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace  \bigcap B = \{1\} \\
  A^c & if\ \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace  \bigcap B = \{0\} \\
  \Omega & if\ \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace  \bigcap B = \{0,1\} \
 \end{array}
\right.
$

$\mathscr{F} = \{
 \emptyset,
 A,
 A^c,
 \Omega
\}
$

**Main question:**
$P(1_A|\mathscr{F}) = ???$

When we try to see $P(1_A|\mathscr{F})$, giving $\mathscr{F}$ doesn't really change anything, because we still have *"unreduced ambiguity"* with respect to $w$.

Can you please explain (or provide link to an explanation) how providing sigma-algebra actually makes "almost sure knowledge of the outcome"?

<sub>[1] James Davidson, Stochastic Limit Theory; 1994; page 114</sub>

Comment: The sigma-algebra you're conditioning on, call it $\mathscr{G}$, can be thought of as the sets $A$ such that you can measure whether $X \in A$. The conditional expectation $E[X \mid \mathscr{G}]$ is then the "best guess" as to the value of $X$ based on all those measurements. It is still a random variable, though, because the value depends on whether $X$ is in each set in $\mathscr{G}$.

Comment: It's a bit of a rough analogy, but you might imagine a thermometer. It gives a certain reading but it only claims that reading is correct to within a certain accuracy. This corresponds to a sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of intervals centered at the possible measured values and whose width is half the error bound for the device. You can now imagine the device measuring whether the temperature is in each of these intervals; once it knows that, it reports a value, and that value is the conditional expectation.

Comment: Of course thermometers don't actually work this way, but you get the point I hope.

Comment: @Ian for the sake of simplicity, I thought to stay exclusively with conditional probability definitions. What I don't get is if I give $\sigma$ of thermometer (not sub-$\sigma$) I really do not decrease any uncertainty. With sub-$\sigma$ it is more or less intuitive, but with $\sigma$, not really.

Comment: FWIW, I fail to understand your definition of the events $A_i$. What is $A_1$, say?

Comment: @Did I am sorry if I was unclear. I mean that there are some sets where $w$ is included and there are sets where $w$ is excluded. Thus, giving $\mathscr{F}$ doesn't "clarify" anything. $A_1$ is set with event $w$ occured.

Comment: @CronAcronis I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In my thermometer analogy, you can gain or lose uncertainty by changing the sigma-algebra to one generated by narrower or wider intervals.

Comment: @Ian, this is very good point, thank you. Let's say we take $\mathscr{F}$ with all possible open intervals. Thus we can get appropriate precision. My understanding, that even if you specify all possible open sets to get very precise intervals, nothing really happened. Just defining this $\mathscr{F}$ doesn't make a measurement to happen. So we "can" measure precise, but we didn't measure. In order for measurement to happen some event should occure. But if some event(not all possible) occured, it means that some sub-$\mathscr{G}$ is present where this event takes place.

Comment: Then what is $w$? The question states "$w\in A_i$", indicating that $w$ is an element of $\Omega$, but your comment mentions the event $w$, which would mean that $w$ is an element of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: @Did, $w$ is an event and is in $\Omega$. You are right, I meant that is in some set of $\mathscr{F}$. But it can be present or not in different sets $A_i \in \mathscr{F}$. Thus, we don't know, did it happen or not :)

Comment: @CronAcronis The event occurring is where the "the conditional expectation is still a random variable" part comes in. Thus in the analogy, there is a real temperature, we use our thermometer and we get a measurement out, which depends on what the real temperature was.

Comment: No, **events are not in $\Omega$**, events are **subsets** of $\Omega$. (Note that this type of confusion is probably exactly the reason why you are lost here.)

Comment: @Ian, looks like I didn't get it yet again. Would you mind to make two examples with thermometer, where we condition probability on sub-$\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{F}$. With sub-$\mathscr{F}$ I more or less get it ("temperature is lower than zero"), so we have our event-space reduced. But what is an example with given $\mathscr{F}$?

Comment: The point is that if you know whether $X$ is in any measurable set $A$, then (because $X$ is a measurable function) you know the actual value of $X$ (at least with probability $1$).

Comment: @Did, just to clarify, is there chance that you meant  "events are subsets of **$\mathscr{F}$**"?

Comment: @CronAcronis No, events are subsets of $\Omega$, specifically those subsets of $\Omega$ which are *elements* of $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: No there is no chance I meant "events are subsets of ℱ". At this point, the best you can do is grab a textbook which has **definitions**...

Comment: @Did have updated the notation according to the definitions.

Comment: Still some mistakes, for example $B\subset\mathbb R$, not $B\in\mathbb R$, but anyway, if $\mathcal F=\{\varnothing,A,A^c,\Omega\}$, then $P(A\mid\mathcal F)=E(\mathbf 1_A\mid\mathcal F)=\mathbf 1_A$ since $A\in\mathcal F$.

Comment: @Did That was my though as well. I don't see how that is ***"almost sure knowledge of the outcome"*** mentioned in the book.